# $f(n) = n^{\log(n)}$, $g(n) = log(n)^{n}$ is $f\in O(g(n))$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$f(n) = n^{\log(n)}$$
 $$g(n) = \log(n)^n$$
 $$f\in O(g(n))\text{ or }f \notin O(g(n))$$

why? I do not seem to get this one in particular

For O (big O)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $n^{\log(n)}=e^{(\log n)^2}$ and $\log(n)^n=e^{n \log(\log(n))}$. Which of the two grows faster?